# PHP preg_replace function

Tags: php, regex

I want to make some changes in my string with preg_replace.
I am using regex but my code does not work.

For example:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want to change all part of string which contain:

```
'The quick brown (REGEX - ALL CHARACTERS: fox, dog, cow) jumps over the lazy dog'
```

to

```
''
```

How can I remove these characters?

Comment: Please elaborate on the `(REGEX...)` part. What exactly does it contain? Any three letters?

Comment: NO, I know start "The quick brown" and know end "jumps over the lazy dog" but between this parts may be everything. I want to remove from my string this text. "The quick brown" + ? + "jumps over the lazy dog"

Comment: @GiorgiTabatadze: "everything" (except a newline)  is `(.+?)`

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead and lookbehind assertions to remove any characters in between "brown" and "jumps".

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";    
echo preg_replace("/(?<=brown).*(?=jumps)/", "", $string);
```

This removes any characters which are preceded by "brown" and followed by "jumps". `.*` means 0 or more of any character other than a newline.

Alternatively, if you prefer to use capture groups:

```
echo preg_replace("/(brown).*(jumps)/", "$1$2", $string);
```

This captures "brown" and "jumps" into the groups `$1` and `$2` then uses them in the replacement string, leaving out the middle part.

Output (using either approach):

```
The quick brownjumps over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 $str = "The quick brown (REGEX - ALL CAHRACTE: fox, dog, cow) jumps over the lazy dog";
 preg_replace('/(The quick brown )(.*)( jumps over the lazy dog)/', '$1$3', $str);
```

A very good place to check your regex in action is: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You want to replace fox with a null value like this?

```
The quick brown  jumps over the lazy dog
```

Then simply do this:

```
<?php
    $string = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

    $pattern = '/\bfox\b/i';

    $new_string = preg_replace($pattern, null, $string);

    echo $new_string;
?>
```